# How to retrieve specifier names for device in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to retrieve list of specifiers for current device that Android will use when deciding from which folder to take resource? e.g. "large", "port", "hdpi", "v11", "pl" etc.

I need a list of specifiers per device that I can later display or log, this then can help me with tweaks of the layout/settings etc. adjusted per logged/tested device.

in other words I would like to have a method that will return a list (or string combining) all specifiers for current device.

```
getSpecifierList();//hdpi,large,port,v11,pl...
```

Comment: what exactly you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use to get Screen Resolution

```
 int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

switch(density)
{
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
   Toast.makeText(context, "LDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
     Toast.makeText(context, "MDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    Toast.makeText(context, "HDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
     Toast.makeText(context, "XHDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
}
```

Use to get Screen Size

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

switch(screenSize) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Normal screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Small screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Screen size is neither large, normal or small" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: does it mean that I have to create this functionality manually for any "bucket" I want to handle?

Comment: No, it just gives you info of your device. If you device is hdpi, it means your app is getting resources from drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: that what I meant, as there is no native (built-in) functionality to retrieve specifier "hdpi" or "v11" or "pl" I have to handle this manually by checking the API version, language set etc. - manually